# Ensure space between Cards on colapse to small screen in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am trying to make sure that when I view my react website on a small screen my cards have space in between them. Right now when I view on a large screen the cards are spaced evenly, however, on a small screen, they are not spaces. Has anyone encountered that issue?

Here is my code

```
<Row gutter={16} justify="space-between" align="middle">
    {this.state.news.slice(0,4).map((item, key) => ( 
        <Col span={12} md={{span:6}} lg={{span:6}} style={{paddingTop:15,marginTop:10}}>
            <Card
                hoverable
                style={{ width: 230 }}
                cover={<img alt="example" src={item.imageurl} />}
                actions={[
                    <a href={item.url} target="_blank" > Read News</a>,
                ]}>  
                <div style={{fontSize:10,paddingRight:5}}>
                    <Meta  title={item.title} description={item.categories} />
                </div>
            </Card>
        </Col>
    ))}
</Row>
```

[cards on a big screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hwBy.jpg)

[cards on a small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgRuK.png)

Comment: is it antd  UI library?

Comment: Yes, its the antd UI library

Answer (score 0):

You have `style={{ width: 100 }}`,This will keep the width fixed for all screen. take it out and try.

```
 <Card
                 hoverable
                //  style={{ width: 100 }}
                 cover={<img alt="example" src={i.picture.large} />}
                 actions={[
                     <a href='#' target="_blank" > Read News</a>,
                 ]}>  

             </Card>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's all I needed to do.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.